# What's the most efficient way of filtering an array based on the contents of another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

Say I have two arrays, items and removeItems and I wanted any values found in removeItems to be removed from items.

The brute force mechanism would probably be:

```
var animals = ["cow","dog","frog","cat","whale","salmon","zebra","tuna"];
var nonMammals = ["salmon","frog","tuna","spider"];
var mammals = [];
var isMammal;

for(var i=0;i<animals.length;i++){
   isMammal = true;
   for(var j=0;j<nonMammals;j++){
     if(nonMammals[j] === animals[i]){
       isMammal = false;
       break;
     }
   }
   if(isMammal){
     mammals.push(animals[i]);
   }
}
```

This is what? O(N^2)? Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's actually `O(M * N)`.

Probably you could do better sorting the `animals` array first, then doing a binary search. You'll be able to reduce to `O(N * log N)` - well, that's if `log N < M` anyway.

Anyway, if you're working with JS and that runs client-side, then just try to keep amount of data at minimum, or their browsers will yell at you with every request.

Comment: I was just writing something about sorting the lists first as well. You end up with n*lg(n) + m*lg(n) to sort the main list and then search main list m times, which is effectively m*lg(n) - much better than n^2

Answer (score 6):

Basically what you want to do is efficiently compute the set difference S \ T. The (asymptotically) fastest way I know is to put T into a hashmap (that makes |T| steps) and go over each s in S (that makes |S| steps) checking wether s in T (which is O(1)). So you get to O(|T| + |S|) steps.

Comment: While this _is_ faster than my answer, it requires more memory for the hash table. There're pros and cons everywhere, right? :) Anyway, I believe this is the best solution, so there goes my +1.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote the asymptotically there. ;) Personally I'd guess that for small inputs even the squared solution suffices.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery it's pretty easy:

```
function is_mammal(animal)
{
    return $.inArray(animal, nonMammals) == -1;
}

mammals = $.grep(animals, is_mammal);
```

See docs for [`$.grep`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.grep#arraycallbackinvert) and [`$.inArray`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.inArray#valuearray).

Comment: That's easy, but doesn't make it any better than O(N^2). Just because you "hide" the loops doesn't mean $.inArray() and $.grep() don't have them.